# Why does the RTA Base Cabinet with Trash Can Pullout cost $669, while the identical Base Cabinet is priced at $261?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, trash-can

- Brilliant White Shaker 15" Base Cabinet with Single Trashcan Pullout -- $669

  https://www.thertastore.com/brilliant-white-shaker-15-base-cabinet-with-single-trashcan-pullout-102399.html
- Brilliant White Shaker 15" Base Cabinet--$261

  https://www.thertastore.com/brilliant-white-shaker-15-base-cabinet-47541.html

**Am i missing something important that is included in the extra $400 are required for Trash Can pull out assembly ?**

Comment: I wouldn't bat an eye at that - somebody else figured out the right hardware and installed it so I don't have to.

Comment: Unless you’re the manufacturer, any answer here is opinion based. Vtc.

Comment: Can you do better for less? No? Then take it or leave it. It may also be helpful, when comparison shopping, to not worry about the prices of individual pieces and instead just compare the total price for the whole job.

Answer (score 1):

Basic economics.  The pullout cabinet uses more materials and is less commonly used, so lower demand, both of which lead to higher prices.